# how to set json attribute using const value

Tags: json

I want to make Json attribute using const data
like this.

```
const title = 'NAME'
data = {title: 'This is title'}
console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

I want this result
=> {NAME: 'This is title'}

but this shown
=> {title: 'This is title'}

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic key, you can use `[variableName]` notation.

So change `title` **to** `[title]`

```js
const title = 'NAME'
data = {[title]: 'This is title'}
console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Comment: Thank you for your surprising, quick and accurate response.
I wish you good luck all the time.